# ¿Por qué GIT de azure no me revierte los cambios?

Tags: asp.net, razor, azure, azure-storage

Tengo un proyecto que estoy realizando en ASP.Net, usando Visual Studio, un compañero ha subido(protegido) una versión que ha destruido por completo la mía, he intentado revertir los cambios, pero el error continua.

**¿Cómo puedo revertir mi proyecto al completo y que no me queden restos?**

Estoy usando:

- Visual Studio 2018
- Azure DevOps(Sistema Git)
- Google Chrome DevOps

Otros datos:

En su subida está package.config que creo que es lo que me ha generado todo este problema, también ha subido el Web.config que sospecho que puede influir también junto con un sin fin de packages de nuget.

**Editado 1**

Después de un ratillo largo he copiado y pegado una versión muy antigua de `package.config` y me ha saltado el siguiente error al ejecutar:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
 'Autofac' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del 
ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT:
 0x80131040)
```

**Editado 2**
Haciendo una comparativa en los paquetes vi que faltaba una referencia a autofac.Integration.Mvc Solucioné este error insertando la referencia a pelo, ya que desde NuGet no funcionaba.

```
Referencias(click derecho)> Agregar Referencia > Examinar > (Ruta Proyecto)App\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.4.0.2\lib\net45
```

Nuevo error en Paquete Microsoft.Owin al intentar instalarlo desde NuGet, error con el la referencia al paquete Owin1.0, lo genera cada vez que se intenta instalar y me hace reiniciar Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de mil intentos he logrado que acceda, la solucion fue:

> 1. Eliminar los paquetes desde el disco
> 2. Coger una versión antigua de `packages.config`
> 3. Actualizar e instalar los paquetes

No ha solucionado el problema del todo. Pero ya puedo acceder a la web y ejecutarla.